# How can I subtract automatically every minute certain quantity?

Tags: charts, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I have a tank of Milk of 50,000lbs that, for example, every minute gets pump out 68lbs, and I want to create in Sheets the current state of that tank every minute in a percentage. Basically, a formula that subtracts X quantity every minute, so I can create a graph of the current state of the tank that gets updated every minute.

I'm working in Google Sheets.

Comment: Your function will be `y = 50,000 - 68 * x` , where x is the time in minutes. Generate a help column with minutes passed, this will be your 'x' e.g. 1,2,3...n and drag the formula down

Answer (score 1):

So the formula will be `y = 50,000 - 68 * x`, where y is the amount of milk remaining in the tank and x is the amount of minutes passed.

[image]

At the given flow you provided (68lbs/minute) it takes approximately 735 minutes to empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&QUOTIENT(B2, B1)+2))-1, 
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&QUOTIENT(B2, B1)+2)) <= 
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&QUOTIENT(B2, B1)+2))))*
 {B2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(-B1&"♦", QUOTIENT(B2, B1)+1), "♦"))}), SIGN(
 {B2; TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(-B1&"♦", QUOTIENT(B2, B1)+1), "♦"))})^0)})
```

[image: 0]

## [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Mm1fSzA5JkVJZ512nWKpktILpTqZysuYpvD74G8UX08/copy)